# Find the count of occurrences of one int in an int array and print it sorted

Tags: java, arrays, sorting

There's an int array:

```
int[] arr = new int[] {8, 9, 7, 6, 7, 8, 8, 9};
```

How do I count the number of occurrences of each number and then sort it so the print of the numbers and their occurrences show in the ascending order? Like this:

```
6(1) 7(2) 8(3) 9(2)
```

Without using any libraries, just loops and ifs, what's the most efficient way?

Comment: Use `TreeMap` where the key will be the int in the array and value its occurrence count.

Comment: Questions asking for *homework help* **must** include a summary of the work you've done so far to solve the problem, and a description of the difficulty you are having solving it ([help], [ask]).

Comment: Just iterate the array and setup a `Map<Integer, Integer>` where you associate the values with their occurrence. Update the counter every time you see a value again. A `HashMap` provides fast access for the `contains` question. A `TreeSet` makes sorting trivial. For small arrays like that performance is not relevant and you can go for the `TreeSet` with the minor slower `contains` method.

Comment: @Zabuza, I think this is a homework assignment - and it explicitly forbids any *libraries*. On the other side, there is no attempt at all...

Comment: That approach does not include a *library*. But yeah, it's not just *loops and ifs*. However, OP needs to be more specific about the restrictions, for example are arrays allowed? Or lists? Or sets?

Comment: @Zabuza, I agree - you made a clear point. I think that only arrays are allowed (not for sure, of course)

Comment: this seems like a good candidate for  a `groupingBy` --> `sorted` --> `toMap`.

Comment: An array-only approach would technically work the same like the map approach, but would be super inefficient as `contains` is super slow and the final size is not known (only bound by the input size). In either case, we should just wait for OP to clarify things and improve the question ([ask]).

Comment: just so you wanted to know, the solution using a `groupingBy` etc... [**ideone**](https://ideone.com/JPCh5J)

Answer (score 0):

```
    int[] arr = new int[] {8, 9, 7, 6, 7, 8, 8, 9};
    Map<Integer, Integer> map = new TreeMap<>(); // TreeMap sorts keys in their natural order
    for(int i : arr) {
        if(!map.containsKey(i)) { // if map doesn't contain currently checked int as a key...
            map.put(i, 1); // put it to map with corresponding value equal to one
        } else { // it this int is already in map...
            map.put(i, map.get(i) + 1); // put it into map with incremented value
        }
    }
    System.out.println(map.entrySet());
```

Output that you get:

```
    [6=1, 7=2, 8=3, 9=2]
```

Comment: I think using a `Map` contradicts with OPs specifications of "*only loops and ifs*", but the specifications are not very clear at the moment.

Comment: I don't think the OP wants this... He explicitly asked for an answer without using (what he/she called) libraries - and `Map` is some kind of 'library'

Comment: I thought that java.util might be considered as an acceptable choice, ok then, I'll try to improve it, but... maybe let's wait for some explanations made by OP because it's a bit unclear for now then.

Answer (score 0):

**Finding occurrences:**  Try creating a second array where you use the number in your to-be-sorted array as the index to this new array and update the value at that index by 1.  This will store the occurrences of your to-be-sorted array in O(n) time, assuming you don't have to resize your array.  If you could use libraries I would recommend using a hashmap though.

**Sorting:**  Hope this doesn't come off as "look it up yourself" type of answer but see if you can search up sorting algorithms.  There are a bunch of them, ranging from bubble sort (easy to code but slow) to quick-sort (harder to code but quicker).  Should be plenty of java tutorials for simple sorting algorithms online that have exactly what you are looking for.

Comment: Your counting method is a form of what is known as **CountingSort** and will only work well if the values are known to have a small upper bound (drawn from a small *universe*). It trivially sorts too, no need for another sorting method. Just iterate the array and leave out everything with count `0`, trivially sorted. So your `O(n)` actually refers to the size of the *universe*, not the size of the input (which, without restrictions, is the whole range of integer).